# How make a smooth scroll menu anchor for a onepage site?

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions, custom-action

I have a website made with Joomla 3.x and make a menu (Agence, Regie Pub, Sites Internet, Autres Services, Realisations and Contact), I want when I click on each of them they redirected to the section in the page smootly. Before I used the extension smooth scroll anchor of PLUGINARIA but now he don't work anymore because is not free. Now I want to make my own smooth scroll by create a custom javascript file in my template helix 3 Framework.

This is the code of my menu :

```
<div class="sp-megamenu-wrapper">
   <a id="offcanvas-toggler" class="visible-sm visible-xs" href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
   </a>
   <ul class="sp-megamenu-parent menu-fade hidden-sm hidden-xs">
      <li class="sp-menu-item current-item active"></li>
         <li class="sp-menu-item">
            <a class="scrollTo" href="#agence">Agence</a>
         </li>
         <li class="sp-menu-item">
            <a class="scrollTo" href="#regie-pub">Régie pub</a>
         </li>
         <li class="sp-menu-item">
            <a class="scrollTo" href="#sites-internet">Sites internet</a>
         </li>
         <li class="sp-menu-item">
            <a class="scrollTo" href="#autres-services">Autres services</a>
         </li>
         <li class="sp-menu-item">
            <a class="scrollTo" href="#realisations">Réalisations</a>
         </li>
         <li class="sp-menu-item">
            <a class="scrollTo" href="#contact">Contact</a>
         </li>
   </ul>
```

I want know how can I do that with this kind of menu that I have. How can I make I smooth scroll anchor to the differente section of my onepage site.

Best regards,
Lordaker

Comment: And I want when I click on a one menu he get an active class. How do that I try with code but all my "li" take the class active.

Answer (score 1):

Aa vanilla Javascript (faster than jQuery) approch would be as follows:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    function scrollTo(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var id = event.target.getAttribute('href').replace('#', '');
        var el = document.getElementById(id);

        if (el) {
            el.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start'});
        }
    }

    var menuLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.scrollTo');

    if (menuLinks.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < menuLinks.length; i++) {
            menuLinks[i].addEventListener('click', scrollTo);
        }
    }
}
```

On Internet Explorer and Safari, you won't get the animated scroll as neither of these browsers support options within the `scrollIntoView()` function

Answer (score 0):

This javascript code I use :

```
    //Smooth Scroll Menu
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('ul.sp-megamenu-parent li.sp-menu-item > a').on('click', function(){

       //Toggle Class
       $(".active").removeClass("active");    
       $(this).closest('li').removeClass("active");
       var theClass = $(this).attr("class");
       $('.'+theClass).parent('li').addClass('active');

       //Animate
       $('html, body').stop().animate({
          scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top - 0
       }, 450);

       return false;

    });
});
```